# Which one is right on ubuntu node or nodejs ? How do get the current working version?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am try to install *webpack-dev-server* but it need latest version of nodejs as i am on *ubuntu 20.04* and when i try to update with nvm and it didn't update nodejs and it try to remove it with this Q&A answer https://askubuntu.com/a/786019 and after that i try to install nodejs `sudo apt-get install nodejs` , npm `sudo apt-get install npm` and even try to get latest nodejs with **n** offical package after all of this when i type `node -v` it says `v16.13.1` which is the latest stable version and when i type `nodejs -v` it says `v10.19.0` which is the version which i get form ubuntu package manager but when i type `npm -v` it throw this gibberish

````
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}```

after all How do i get the latest working version of nodejs which is i can run npm,and how do i remove this confusion what to use and what to install next time when i try to update
````

Comment: did you use `nvm use {{desired_version}}`? replace `{{desired_version}}` with the version you installed.

Comment: @Schwieriiiiig now I don't even have node js installed on my machine, I am trying this https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve it by my own so i google a lot but the problem was with the PPAs and after make so many mistakes it install with the official nodejs github documentation. so the problem is solved : )